# Golang | Is it possible to calculate a power value without using math library?

Tags: go

I am wondering how can we calculate a power value withing using `math` library?

I have checked the method for calculating a power value that most of the ways are using the `math` library to achieve (i.e., `math.Pow`).

For example, if we wanna calculate 3^2, we can do the way like `3**2` in Python, so I am curious is it possible to do a similar way like Python via math symbols to calculate it in Go?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid math.Pow? If this is some kind of "package golf": Try avoiding package io, strings and error. And try to avoid `if`.

Comment: I am just curious. If there is an alternatively simple way, of course, I will not use the way of importing a library.

Comment: For reference as to why I looked this up: Golang 1.21 added max and min functions despite them already having a variation in the math package, saying that they are considered "basic mathematical procedures". I guess it just surprises me that real, imag, complex, max, and min are ALL categorized as basic mathematical procedures needing to be built in but an actual basic math procedure taught in elementary school is not. I have yet to need functions like real, complex, or imag (or there corresponding types), but have often needed pow. I have no problem importing packages, it just surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no Go operator ("math symbols") to do this, though if the exponent is constant you could of course just write `x*x` for x^2, or `x*x*x` for x^3.

If the exponent is not constant but is an integer, a simple way to calculate n^exp is to use repeated multiplication, something like this:

```golang
func pow(n float64, exp int) float64 {
    if exp < 0 { // handle negative exponents
        n = 1 / n
        exp = -exp
    }
    result := 1.0
    for i := 0; i < exp; i++ {
        result *= n
    }
    return result
}
```

That said, I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to avoid `math.Pow` -- it's in the standard library and it's faster and more general.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I do not avoid to use `math.Pow`, and I just wanna know is there any simple way to achieve the same results without importing the library.

Comment: Helps not to import much of a standard library when building interpreters, which is why I looked this up.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are integer, then this should work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    number := 4
    power := 5
    result := 1

    for power != 0 {
        result = result * number
        power = power - 1
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```